# datadog agent not reachable from inside docker container

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, localhost, statsd, datadog

I installed dd-agent on Amazon linux ec2. If I run my python script directly on the host machine (I used the SDK named "dogstatsd-python"), all the metrics can be sent to datadog (I logged in to datadoghq.com and saw the metrics there). 
the script is something like:

```
from statsd import statsd
statsd.connect('localhost', 8125)
statsd.increment('mymetrics')
```

However, I launched a docker container and run the same script from inside the container:

```
from statsd import statsd
statsd.connect('172.14.0.1', 8125)
statsd.increment('my metrics')
```

'172.14.0.1' is the IP of the host, which was extracted with command

```
netstat -nr | grep '^0\.0\.0\.0' | awk '{print $2}'
```

No metrics were sent to datadog at all.....

I'm guessing that maybe it's due to some configuration issue like "address binding". Maybe the dd-agent I installed on the host can only receive metrics from 'localhost'.

Hope someone could help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you figure out a fix?. I set `non_local_traffic: yes` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 11):

You will need to set `non_local_traffic: yes` in your `/etc/dd-agent/datadog.conf` file. Otherwise the agent will reject metrics from containers.

After setting, you will need to restart the agent for the change to take effect: `sudo /etc/init.d/datadog-agent restart` or `sudo service datadog-agent restart`

The [docker-dd-agent](https://github.com/DataDog/docker-dd-agent) image enables `non_local_traffic: yes` by default.

Comment: In the latest version, the file is /etc/datadog-agent/datadog.conf, not dd-agent.

Comment: This is exactly what was needed.
My setup: 
OS Windows server 2016  
datadog agent on host. 
windows containers. 

leaving the details for others who may need.

Comment: I ran this in Docker and for me the easiest way to get this to work was with the environment variable DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC=True.  See also https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/docker/?tab=standard#dogstatsd-custom-metrics.

Answer (score 3):

If `dd-agent` listens on `localhost` it can receive data only from localhost (127.0.0.1). Try to change the `dd-agent` host to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`.

We are using [docker-dd-agent](https://github.com/DataDog/docker-dd-agent) and it works OOTB.

Comment: Thank you! I changed "bind_host" from "localhost" to "0.0.0.0" in /etc/dd-agent/datadog.conf. and restarted dd-agent. But the problem still exists..... is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: Yes, I know the dd-agent docker image. But for some reason, we try to avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually want to use the IP of the host in this case. If you're running the docker dd-agent, there are two environment variables you can tap into:

`statsd.connect(DOGSTATSD_PORT_8125_UDP_ADDR, DOGSTATSD_PORT_8125_UDP_PORT)`

That should do the trick. If not, you should be able to find the relevant info to your problem in [this section of the Datadog docs](https://github.com/DataDog/docker-dd-agent#dogstatsd-from-the-host).

Also, I should point out that the only Python library that Datadog shows in their docs is [datadogpy](https://github.com/DataDog/datadogpy).

Answer (score 0):

Here are instructions for Datadog version and Ubuntu Linux. The config vars have changed a bit:

```
Agent 7.35.2 - Commit: edd49be - Serialization version: v5.0.16 - Go version: go1.17.6
```

Check `nano /etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml`:

```yaml
# Remember to enable this section
apt_config:
    apm_non_local_traffic: true
    dogstatsd_non_local_traffic: true
```

Then:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart datadog-agent
```

and:

```bash
sudo datadog-agent status
```